# How to load files with dependencies in Sinatra. Testing

Tags: dependencies, sinatra

My `spec_helper` in my Sinatra app looks like this:

```
$LOAD_PATH << '../lib'
require 'pry'
require 'helpers/data_helper.rb'
Dir[File.join("lib/*.rb")].each do |f|
  require f
end
```

The problem is that my first class looks like this:

```
class HouseDistributer < Distributer
   ...
end
```

`Distributer` is a dependency but it hasn't loaded yet. What am I supposed to do? What is a good way around this?

Comment: what is `Distributer` - is it your code or a library?

Comment: My code is the distributor class